# Kendo Spreadsheet Unique Value Validation Rule

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm trying to set a validation rule on my "email" column so that all rows inserted by user contain unique emails. 
Normally i would do something like this with a counif formula. 
My problem is that i want this to be dynamic and apply to each new row.

```
validation: {
from:"AND(COUNTIF(A:A,A3)=1)",
dataType: "custom",
messageTemplate: "Email must be unique",
type: "reject"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later edit: I've managed to solve this by creating a validation row on the column itsel
`var emailRange = spreadShit.activeSheet().range("A1:A100");
            emailRange.validation({
                dataType: "custom",
                from: "AND(COUNTIF($A:$A,$A1)=1)",
                type: "reject",
                titleTemplate: "Duplicate Email validation error",
                messageTemplate: "Email addresses must be unique"
            });`